# How to quick launch server with winginx?

Tags: php, nginx, winginx

Im searching a way to start server with a bat file or by adding a prefix to a shortcut to launch a winginx program with a specific project and specific services (php, nginx, mysql)

ps: i dont need install services. Its portable server.

thanks

Comment: You can use the service installer from here http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/
 which will work for any nginx windows version.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a .bat file that will use the cd(change directory) command to change the current directory to the location of the services and then execute each service command